# WinXP password messed up after reset

Tags: windows, passwords

I changed my winXP logon password - but could not get in. Obviously I made the some mistake twice... caps lock or something but couldn't get the password.

So I booted into safe mode, when into Users and changed the password.

Now I when I restart I can get in at logon with my new password, but the standard screensaver - which used to be the same as my user logon - now is something different. I think it's still the previous one which I couldn't get right.

Now when I go into Users (not in safe mode) and try and change the password I can't. It won't accept my new user logon which works fine when logging on. I think this too is still the previous one which I couldn't get right.

How can I definitely reset the password so it works at logon, in the control panel/users, and the screensaver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Boot with a password reset boot disc such as **[PCLoginNow](http://www.pcloginnow.com/)**.

   [image]
2. Clear all account passwords to blank (do not set a new password using this disc)
3. Once cleared boot into Windows to set a new password.

Answer (score 0):

You can try two methods to solve this problem:

1. Boot to Safe Mode with a Command Prompt. After it boots up, type this into the console:

   ```
   net user <username> *
   ```

   *Where <username> is the username whose password you want to reset.*

   Note: When entering the new password it won't appear, so be careful while typing.
2. Use [Hiren's BootCD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd) and reset your password.

Answer (score 0):

**[ntpasswd](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/)** is a good counter-password measure. It can be used on a bootable USB stick to your liking.